# Why does my IntegerField, used to create a dropdown menu, not work?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I cannot seem to make my Django model work properly. The thing is, that my dropdown menu returns a number instead of "ja" or "nej" (meaning yes or no in Danish). However, when I create the model inside of the admin-panel, everything works perfectly fine. But as soon as I try to display the data on the front-end, stuff goes wrong.

I have provided the code, in case you wanted to have a look.

```
YESNO_CHOICES = (
    (0, 'Ja'),
    (1, 'Nej')
    )

class Client(models.Model):
    fulde_navn = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tidligere_klient = models.IntegerField(choices=YESNO_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    beskrivelse = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    arbejde = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    relateret_til_andre_klienter = models.IntegerField(choices=YESNO_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    vurder_sidste_session = models.IntegerField(choices=SESSION_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    profilbillede = models.ImageField('Profile picture',
                                upload_to='profile_pics/%Y-%m-%d/',
                                null=True,
                                blank=True)
```

Front-end part:

```
<div class="container profile-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item"><b>Adresse: </b>{{ client.adresse }}</b></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><b>Tidligere klient: </b>{{ client.tidligere_klient }}</b></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><b>Adresse: </b>{{ client.adresse }}</b></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><b>Adresse: </b>{{ client.adresse }}</b></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><b>Adresse: </b>{{ client.adresse }}</b></li>
```

Comment: How are you showing your dropdown? In a form? If so, post your code, if not, still post your code.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get%5FFOO%5Fdisplay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is stored in the database as integers. To display the Yes/No value, you need to use this:

```
{{ get_tidligere_klient_display }}
```

This will match the value stored in database and display the proper word. Like:

```
{% for client in client_list %} 

    {{ client.get_tidligere_klient_display }}

{% endfor %}
```